# Prevent exe from opening a new command prompt window

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I am on windows 7 command prompt. When I run the following command

```
"C:\Program Files\abc.exe" help  > out.txt
```

abc.exe is a third party program which displays some info. What happens is that a new window opens up, abc.exe help prints the output on the new window, the window then closes and I get back to my original window. The out.txt file remains empty.

How can I prevent abc.exe from opening a new window. Can I force it to display its output on the same original window so that it can be redirected to out.txt.

Comment: Can you post some of the abc.exe code?

Comment: @demonofnight: The question says `abc.exe` is a **third party program**, which means that's probably unlikely.

Comment: Its an EMC program to get some details about the storage system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to solve this.

In windows there is an option called "Open command prompt as Administrator". A new window does not open up in that case.

Comment: Works for me. But why? @Sumedh do you have any explanation?

Comment: I have no idea, why this works.

Answer (score 2):

It may be that the application doesn't output to STDOUT or STDERR but try this

```
"C:\Program Files\abc.exe" help  > out.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: That did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, running as admin would solve the problem, but that couldn't be an acceptable answer as non-admins were also having this issue. The output redirection idea didn't help because it would redirect the output from the non elevated prompt - which had no output. So it just creates an empty file.

My issue was the .exe I was calling had been configured to run elevated. The cmd prompt I was launching from was not running as an admin and it can't be elevated after it has started. So it would launch a new elevated window to run the command, which would complete in the blink of an eye and then exit leaving me with my non-elevated prompt with no output.

Solution A: Run cmd/powershell as administrator. Then it can run within the same window.
Solution B: Change the .exe to not run as administrator so it doesn't need to launch a new elevated window. This is the option I went with.